# How to compute an indefinite integral for a general parameter choice?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to compute the integral:

```
Integrate[E^(a*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (1 - x)]), x]
```

for `a >= 0`. The computation times out unless I provide a specific numerical value for `a`. For example for `a = 0.5`, I get an output. Is there a way to get the integral expression in terms of `a`?

Comment: I think just wait. I eventually got the result: `ConditionalExpression[E^(a^2/2)/2 + 1/2 E^(a^2/2)Erf[a/Sqrt[2] + InverseErfc[2 - 2 x]], ! (x <= 0 || (! 0 < x <= 1 && x > 1))]`

Comment: @thorimur Using `Simplify` on `! (x <= 0 || (! 0 < x <= 1 && x > 1))` gets one `0 < x <= 1`.

Comment: nice, yeah! i was just copy-pasting the result verbatim to show it finished 

Comment: Include assumptions: `Assuming[a >= 0 && 0 <= x <= 1, Integrate[E^(a*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (1 - x)]), x]]`